# How to obtain data of retweets in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, twitter4j, tweets

I'm doing an app using the `twitter4j api`, to obtain my tweets, followers, friends, mentions and retweets.

Everything ok, but I can obtain the text of the retweet, however I can't obtain info about the retweeter, that is I want.

Here is my code (*Sorry, maybe it can be primitive, but are my first steps*).

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val retweets = twitter.getRetweetsOfMe()
     println("Mis retweets")
     for (i <- 0 until retweets.size()) {
        retweets.get(i).getUser()
     } 
}
```

The problem is that I obtain only my Id, but not the Id of the retweeter.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to know who retweeted your tweets?

`Twitter.getRetweetsOfMe()` method will only tweets of you that is retweeted by others.

Those tweets will be a collection of `Status` objects in twitter4j. And, `Status` objects itself do not contain the information about who retweeted this status (tweet).

It only contains info whether or not *you* (the user who logged in) retweeted it, and how many people retweeted it(`Status.getRetweetCount()` method).

So...

If you want to obtain who retweeted some tweet, you can use `Twitter.getRetweets()` method. It will give you at most 100 tweets (retweets of the original tweet), and each will have information about the retweeter.

In your case, you can use like this:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val retweets = twitter.getRetweetsOfMe()
  println("Mis retweets")
  for (i <- 0 until retweets.size()) {
    val tweet = retweets.get(i)
    val rts = twitter.getRetweets(tweet.getId())
    for (j <- 0 until rts.size()) {
      val user = rts.get(j).getUser()
      println("@" + user.getScreenName() + " retweeted the tweet whose ID is " + tweet.getId())
    }
  } 
}
```

I didn't compile it, so it may have errors. However, you can see what is going on from this code. Also, it may be slow because it will connect to Twitter server each time you call `getRetweets()` method.

cf.) If you want to get all of the retweeters of one tweet that is retweeted more than 100 times, it is not possible according to Twitter Dev homepage: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14611